# What gives a better efficiency. SimpleCursorAdapter or a normal adapter?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, adapter, simplecursoradapter

I need to get information that becomes from an external API client and show that information with an adapter.
My application must use retrofit to get the info from the API, save it into the database (sqlite) and show it using an adapter. An important think to consider is that I wont use retrofit every time I start my application (maybe I update the database once everyday or everyweek).

The dilemma comes when I dont know if I should use a SimpleCursorAdapter so I cannot directly update the adapter with the info I get from retrofit because I have to download the info, introduce the into the database and extract it from databse to show into adapter; or a normal adapter wich can update the adapter directly when i get the info from retrofit but when I dont want to use retrofit and i want just to get info from database I will have to create objects from the info i get from database to update it.

BTW i'm programming in Android. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplicity vs Customizability.

For me, I always choose default Adapter and create an inherited class as it gives more customizability. That's same reason of what you are saying;

> when I dont want to use retrofit and i want just to get info from database I will have to create objects from the info i get from database to update it...

Sometimes the app might require cache (some temporary variable), or complex list output that cannot do only with single query.

Comment: Well, in this case my dilemma is about efficiency. With normal adapter, accesing to database and creating each object may be very expensive, but im not sure at all... In the other case we have the SimpleCursorAdapter that just get the database info and shows it.

Comment: @Aviletti // if the requirement can be achieved with simple query, `SimpleCursorAdapter` is better to go as it just _simple_ for efficiency.

Comment: I'm such a novice but I apreciate that other people help newbies. Thanks a lot!